# Extract rows for columns that exceeds threshold, with delimiters in columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

My data file is as follow:

```
name,age,quote,children
Mary,50,Love For All, Hatred For None.,3
John,61,I think, therefore, I am,2
June,42,You're braver than you believe, and stronger than you seem, and smarter than you think,1
```

I'd like to extract rows where children >1, to output.txt. However I can't really specify column $4 since there's commas in the column `quote`.

How should I approach this? I've tried `awk -F, '$-1 > 1' data > output.txt`, but it doesn't read $-1 like python/java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk, the last field value is accessible by the `$NF`, second last `$(NF-1)`, etc based on the field separator. so you need

```
awk -F, '$NF > 1' data
```

Ps, and don't forget to fix the source program that produce that invalid .csv file at first place.